# How to make animated object made in figma to work in website?

Tags: animation, button, figma

I have followed a youtube tutorial and made an animated button in Figma to switch dark/light theme.
I see I can copy CSS code to use in my editor, but I can't see how to keep that animation on website?

Basically, in "light" mode, it has lightblue background with sun on it, and when clicked it transitions to "dark" mode, with dark purple background and halfmoon on it.

Is there a way to transfer that animation to website?

Could I paste a link to that YT video here, as I can't explain better?

Thanks in advance, Zoran